# How to check time required by a Unit test (whole class)

Tags: java, junit, rule

I have around 5000 unit tests in my project and I am trying to record time taken by each unit test. I cannot edit the @Before and @After by going into each and every unit test.

I am trying to use @Rule but somehow that is not helping, I was not even able to get it to work but my changing annotation to @ClassRule and making my watcher static I was able to atleast get hold of beggining and end of unit test execution, I just dont know the name of the unit test. Here is my Code:

I have a class called IIMUnitTest (parent class) and all Unit tests extend this class.

I added the following code to the IIMUnitTest

```
@Rule
public TestRule watcher = new TestWatcher() {
    Long timeStart;
    protected void starting(Description description) {
         timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out
                .println("===========================================================================");
        System.out.println("Test: " + description.getMethodName());
        TimeZoneFormat dateFormat = null;
        System.out.println("Start Time: " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
        System.out
                .println("==============================================");
    }

    protected void finished(Description description) {
        Long timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double seconds = (timeEnd-timeStart)/1000.0;
        System.out
                .println("\n============================================================");
        System.out
                .println("Test completed - ran in: "+new DecimalFormat("0.000").format(seconds)+" sec");
        System.out
                .println("========================\n");

    }
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you calling starting() and finished() when starting and finishing a test?

Comment: @Fooble: They're overrides. [TestWatcher calls them automatically.](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.java)

Comment: Set `dateFormat` to something other than null.

Comment: @DonBottstein My bad, that actually worked. But it does system prints after each method. Not after each unit test (Complete class)

Comment: @NickChh `description.getClassName()` will give you the name of the class being tested, which is more appropriate when using `@ClassRule` :-).

Comment: @DonBottstein You are the best. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the rule [StopWatch](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/Stopwatch.html) that is part of JUnit 4.12. It does the calculation for you.